# unix timestamp with millisecond precision in VB6?

Tags: vb6, unix-timestamp

how can i get a unix timestamp with millisecond (or more?) precision in VB6?

(and getting a seconds-precision stamp and multiplying it by 1000 is not an acceptable solution because i need sub-second precision)

Edit: No, [How to get time elapsed in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073269/how-to-get-time-elapsed-in-milliseconds) is not a duplicate of this question, i need to get a unix timestamp since 1970-01-01 00:00:00, while that question just needs to know how much time it took to execute operations, and the answers use GetTickCount() which counts milliseconds **since system reboot**, not since 1970 (and even if i was theoretically running on a computer that was last rebooted in 1970, which i'm not, GetTickCount() has a max limit of 49.7 days, and i don't think such an old system would be running Windows NT anyway, meaning it wouldn't have access to WinAPI's GetTickCount())

Edit2: i don't have a solution yet, but it's probably possible to use GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() to get the numbers, but i don't know how to use 2x 32bit integers as 64bit integer in VB6 to derive the number..

also here is code to run GetSystemTime() in VB6 (thanks to [danaseaman](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23411403/how-can-i-get-system-date-time-in-timestamp-format-in-VB6-0.html) )

```
Private Type SYSTEMTIME
   wYear                As Integer
   wMonth               As Integer
   wDayOfWeek           As Integer
   wDay                 As Integer
   wHour                As Integer
   wMinute              As Integer
   wSecond              As Integer
   wMilliseconds        As Integer
End Type

Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "KERNEL32.dll" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)
```

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1073269/5162073)

Comment: If you truly need millisecond precision, then Brian's and C-Pound's links detail how to accomplish that.  It is simpler, however, if you can just use the built in Timer function - returns a Single with the number of seconds since midnight, the fractional portion of the Single containing fractions of a second.  It only has a resolution of about 10ms, however.

Comment: Do you mean dividing by 1000?

Comment: The proposed duplicate is for calculating an elapsed duration in milliseconds (using something like GetTickCount); this question is asking about the absolute time (just in unix format). I think it's a different enough question.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru no it's not a duplicate of that question. i have edited the post to explicitly explain why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkL unofrunately not, their link does not explain how to get a millisecond-precision unix timestamp (aka milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00), but maybe 10 millisecond precision is OK - what Timer function are you talking about?

Comment: Wouldn't a 64-bit integer (Long) just be the upper 32-bit number shifted plus the lower 32-bit number?

Comment: @DaveNewton VB6's "Long" is 32 bits. (Hey, that was pretty long at the time.) There's no native simple 64-bit type, which makes managing such numbers... tricky.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Oops, I stopped at VB and missed the 6.

Comment: VB6 has a built-in Timer function.  No need to add any components or references.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/aa263387(v=vs.60) for a very brief explanation.

Comment: @MarkL `Returns a Single representing the number of seconds elapsed since midnight.`  1: that seems to use second-precision, which is insufficient. 2: i don't want the number of seconds since last midnight, i want the number of milli-seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: Yes, Timer returns seconds since midnight, with the fractional portion of the returned Single value providing the fractional seconds, with about 10ms resolution, as I described in my first comment, and described i the MS link.  I don't think you're going to find a native function that will return a Unix Epoch value, you'll need to roll your own. You could use Timer to fetch today's seconds (to 10ms), then calc and add the number of seconds between Jan 1 1970 and the start of today.

Comment: Calculating the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970 is simple:`DateDiff("s", CDate("1/1/1970"), Now)`.  `DateDiff` returns a Variant(Long), you can multiply by 1000 to convert to milliseconds and add in the fraction value from Timer (also multiplied by 1000), but that won't fit in a VB6 Long (32bit signed) so you need to decide on how you're going to represent and store your Epoch value (Single or Double floating point, or a Currency variable type maybe?).

Comment: @MarkL getting a seconds-precision stamp and multiplying it by 1000 is not an acceptable solution because i need sub-second precision. multiplying it by 1000 will not increase the precision. as for the data type, easy, just use a Double.

Comment: One more time: The build-in `Timer` function returns sub-second precision, to about 10ms.  Multiply that by 1000 and you have the number of milliseconds (to about 10ms resolution) since midnight.

Answer (score 3):

Based upon the many comments, here is a simple solution for future readers of this question:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   'https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html

   Dim epoch As Currency

   epoch = (DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", Date) + Timer) * 1000

   Debug.Print Round(epoch)
End Sub
```

The idea is to calculate the number of seconds to midnight, add fractional seconds from midnight, and multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.  The result appears to be accurate according to a number of websites including the one referenced in the code.